# Moralis Web3API react hook returning 400

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web3js, moralis

For some reason, my `getNFTsForContract` web3API call keeps returning 400s, but I can't tell why. Here is what I'm using to make the call:

```js
const { fetch, data, error, isLoading } = useMoralisWeb3ApiCall(
    Web3Api.account.getNFTsForContract,
    {
      chain: networkId,
      address: user,
      token_address: retroCatsAddress,
    }
  )
```

And it looks like in my browser inspect tools that the request body of the API call is ok. I also have setup the MoralisProvider like so:

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <MoralisProvider
    appId={process.env.REACT_APP_MORALIS_APP_ID}
    serverUrl={process.env.REACT_APP_MORALIS_SERVER_URL}
  >
    <App />
  </MoralisProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

But am wondering if I'm missing something. The parameters i'm passing are:

`address`: `0x643315C9Be056cDEA171F4e7b2222a4ddaB9F88D`
`chain`: `4`
`token_address`: `0xc8d8B5a3ED2aA35Df8F1781F2B06A14Fb0411bc8`

And I've verified that the address in question has NFTs on the token_address.

So what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the chain as a string and in hex form:

```
const { fetch, data, error, isLoading } = useMoralisWeb3ApiCall(
    Web3Api.account.getNFTsForContract,
    {
      chain: "0x4",
      address: user,
      token_address: retroCatsAddress,
    }
  )
```

Comment: Thanks! It looks like it needs to be a string in hex form as well. So I needed to convert it from "4" to "0x4"